# How to filter laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, filter, eloquent

I am trying to make a filter in laravel. This following filter works

```
$posts= Post::where('category',$request->category)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);
```

But when I try to do something like this

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $posts= Post::where('category',$request->category)->get();
    $posts->latest()->paginate(10);
    dd($posts);
```

It doesn't work. Can someone explain why is this and provide me the code that works. My project have multiple filter.

Error
[image]

Comment: what laravel version is this? and What does 'it doesn't work' mean, i.e what errors did you see?

Comment: this is laravel 5.5 and I mean lower one code does not work

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: $blogs = Blog::where('category',$request->category)->get();
$blogs->latest()->paginate(10);
dd($blogs); this code give me  if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$method} does not exist.");
        }  and Method latest not found

Comment: when you run the second code, what errors did you get. You can update your questions with the errors you have. This would avoid you getting random or guessed answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$posts = Post::all();` already execute a query.

```
Post::where('category',$request->category)->latest()->paginate(10)->get();
```

would be what you want.

A note:`latest` requires the `created_at` column

Answer (score 0):

You should go

```
$posts = Post::where('category',$request->category)->latest()->paginate(10);
```

the get request is unnecessary as the paginate will execute the query.

Comment: what if $request->category==null

Comment: what do you want to happen when the categoy is null?

Answer (score 0):

The first one makes the query by pagination i.e fetch 10 records per constructed page

For the second one, based on observation, you most likely have encountered at least 2 errors:
The first, on the line that used the `get` method because that method requires at least one parameter.

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()
```

The other since its a collection, and since there is nothing like `paginate` or `latest` method on collection therefore throws other errors. You should check Collection's [Available methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods) to have a glimpse of the methods allowed on collection.

One of the best solutions is to simply order the result when making the query:

```
Blog::where('category',$request->category)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') //you may use also 'updated_at' also depends on your need
    ->paginate(10);
```

This way you have the latest coming first int the pagination and also having not worrying about [paginating a collection](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-paginate-laravel-collection)